# Changing API 23 to API 21

Tags: android

I am developing app in API level 23 (Marshmallow) but some methods and libraries are deprecated in API 23 i need to downgrade project to API 21 or API 22. But when i change my API level and build my project it gives error

[image]

I have tried all methods all things that are mentioned on this forum but none could helped me.. 
is give error for some value-23.xml file.. i have changed the name of that file from value-23.xml to value-22.xml but android studio said "FILE usder the build folder are generated and should not be edited"

Comment: Upload your Gradle file please. Looks like you are using the API 23 support library. Alternatively, explain what is deprecated and we can explain what the correct code is

Comment: Deprecated methods still can be used, and there should have replacement. Google or read the android docs.

Comment: Just continue to use API 23 and everything will be fine for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You have changed your `compileSdkVersion` below 23, but you are still trying to use a version-23 edition of `appcompat-v7`. Change your `appcompat-v7` statement in the `dependencies` of your `build.gradle` file, choosing a version that matches your `compileSdkVersion`. Or, move your `compileSdkVersion` back to 23 and address your deprecation issues in some other fashion.